# Different arguments/return values for sinon expectation

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I'm writing unit tests for my module and use SinonJS to verify a couple of expectations regarding function calls to other modules. First, I register a mock for the other module:

```
var otherModule = {
    getConfig : function () {}
};

mockery.registerMock("otherModule", otherModule);
```

Later on, I run some tests and (successfully) verify some expectations such as:

```
var otherModuleMock = sinon.mock(otherModule);
otherModuleMock
    .expects("getConfig")
    .once()
    .withArgs("A")
    .returns(configValuesForA);

// run test

otherModuleMock.verify(); // <- succeeds
```

I run into a problem however, when the module calls the `getConfig` function twice, with different arguments:

```
otherModuleMock
    .expects("getConfig")
    .once()
    .withArgs("A")
    .returns(configValuesForA);

otherModuleMock
    .expects("getConfig")
    .once()
    .withArgs("B")
    .returns(configValuesForB);
```

From my understanding of the documentation, this should probably work. However, this results in the following error:

```
ExpectationError: Unexpected call: getConfig(A)
    Expectation met: getConfig(A[, ...]) once
    Expectation met: getConfig(B[, ...]) once
```

I tried replacing `once()` with `atLeast(1)` or removing it completely. I also tried capturing the expectation returned by `otherModuleMock.expect("getConfig")` and applying `withArgs` and `returns` on that instead. Both to no avail.

Pretty sure I'm using `mock()` in a way I'm not supposed to, but how should I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the module I was testing actually calls `getConfig` 3 times: Once with `A`, once with `B` and then with `A` again.

And apparently Sinon keeps track of the order of all expectations/calls, which is the reason the test even failed when using `atLeast(1)` instead of `once()`. Makes sense when I look at it now, but these cases are not really documented extensively in the Sinon docs (in my own defence).